# export 'DateRange' (imported as 'DateRange') was not found in '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/DateRangePicker' (possible exports: DateRangePicker)

Tags: reactjs

I wanted to implement date range picker following [date-range-picker](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/)
I copied the code from there but it's giving the above error anyone who ever met this problem?

Comment: I just used different date range picker